# Edit only particular text in a paragraph using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to edit only a particular text. Like

> Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Fusce vel dui. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
> ****Vestibulum**** ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed

in the above paragraph, the bold word can be edited. I wanted to edit only that particular word while other word cannot be accessed. Can i do with reactjs?

Comment: what do you mean with edit the text? make the html editable by the user?

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-building-inline-editable-ui-in-react/

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Paragraph extends React.Component<any, any>{
    public static paragraph = (word:string):string => {
        return `
            Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Fusce vel dui. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. ${word} ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed
        `
    }

    props:React.ComponentProps<any>;
    state:React.ComponentState;

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {paragraph: Paragraph.paragraph('Vestibulum')}
        this.updateWord = this.updateWord.bind(this);
    }
    
    /** call updateWord to update */
    updateWord(word:string):void{
        this.setState({paragraph: Paragraph.paragraph(word)});
    }
    
    render():JSX.Element{
        let styles:React.CSSProperties = {
            height: '450px',
            width: '600px',
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
            margin: '20px',
            padding: '20px',
            border: '1px solid',
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div style={styles}>
                    {this.state.paragraph}
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

function App():JSX.Element{
    return (
        <>
            <Paragraph />
        </>
    );
}
```

I suggestion the learning curve of React:

- Props and State
- React.Compoenent and Styled-Compoennt
- Route

---

You can choose your own way of updating the text using the `setState` method. For instance:

```js
class Paragraph extends React.Component<any, any>{
    public static paragraph = (word:string):string => {
        return `
            Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Fusce vel dui. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. ${word} ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed
        `
    }

    props:React.ComponentProps<any>;
    state:React.ComponentState;

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {paragraph: Paragraph.paragraph('Vestibulum')}
        this.updateWord = this.updateWord.bind(this);
        this.updateFromInput = this.updateFromInput.bind(this);
    }

    updateWord(word:string):void{
        this.setState({paragraph: Paragraph.paragraph(word)});
    }

    updateFromInput(e:any):void{
        this.updateWord(e.target.value);
    }

    render():JSX.Element{
        let styles:React.CSSProperties = {
            height: '450px',
            width: '600px',
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
            margin: '20px',
            padding: '20px',
            border: '1px solid',
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div style={styles}>
                    {this.state.paragraph}
                </div>
                <input 
                    defaultValue={'Vestibulum'}
                    onChange={this.updateFromInput}
                >
                </input>
            </>
        )
    }
}


function App():JSX.Element{
    return (
        <>
            <Paragraph />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Where are you updating the word? This is wrong.

Comment: @goto1, there are many ways of updating by using `setState` function, I added an example for immediate update from input in addition.

Comment: For the OP, if you are using JSX instead of TSX, you can get rid of all types after comma.